# Error handler ignored when NODE_ENV=production

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, error-handling

I am building a simple REST API with Node/Express, and I'm having a hard time when I deploy it to production. When `NODE_ENV=development`, everything works as expected. I get back the JSON error and the correct status code. When `NODE_ENV=production`, I only get back an HTML page with the default error message and nothing else. I can read the status code, but I need to have access to the full JSON payload to identify the errors better. This is my code:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import express from 'express';
import config from './config';
import routes from './routes';
import { errorMiddleware, notFoundMiddleware } from './middlewares/error.middleware';
import mongoose from './config/mongoose.config';

// create app
const app = express();

(async () => {
  // connect to mongoose
  await mongoose.connect();

  // pretty print on dev
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    app.set('json spaces', 2);
  }

  // apply express middlewares
  app.use(express.json());

  // register v1 routes
  app.use('/v1', routes);

  // catch errors
  app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
  app.use(errorMiddleware);

  // start server
  app.listen(config.port, () => console.info(`server started on port ${config.port}`));
})();

export default app;
```

This is the `notFoundMiddleware`:

`export default (req, res, next) => next(new Error('Not Found'));`

This is the `errorMiddleware`:

```
const errorMiddleware = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log('test'); // this works in development, but not in production
  const error = {
    status: err.status,
    message: err.message
  };

  if (err.errors) {
    error.errors = err.errors;
  }

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && err.stack) {
    error.stack = err.stack;
  }

  return res.status(error.status || 500).send({ error });
};
```

Comment: em... you have `if` when you have production mode then you don't send stack trace only message and status.```if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && err.stack) {
    error.stack = err.stack;
  }```

Comment: @DmytroMysak Yeah, that's because I don't want the stack on production. The problem is that I'm not getting the status or message either.

Comment: From the npm module document, it looks like you have to use ApiErrorsMiddleware to get JSON response.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem, can you show us an example for where you return the error that invokes the error handler? (e.g. `next(new Error..`)

Comment: Your code looks correct. Do you use reverse proxy when running with `NODE_ENV` production?

Comment: Do you see the output of console.log('test')  when in production mode?

Comment: Are you serving your API under NGINX or something like that?

Comment: Maybe in production conf file debug flags are set to false?

Comment: need more details see @DatTran's comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are runing on production server, try to use some logging provider like "papertrailapp" to see the error occurs in your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon the same problem. It turned out it's caused by a transpiler optimization applied when building production bundle - this one: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-minify-dead-code-elimination

Express' error handlers should have the signature `(err, req, res, next) => { ... }` (be of arity 4). In your example `next` is not used anywhere in `errorMiddleware` function body and thus it gets eliminated (optimized-out) from function signature in production code.

**Solution**:

- use `keepFnArgs: true` plugin option - possibly through https://webpack.js.org/plugins/babel-minify-webpack-plugin/ webpack configuration:

  ```js
  var MinifyPlugin = require("babel-minify-webpack-plugin")
  module.exports = {
      // ...

      optimization: {
          minimizer: [
              new MinifyPlugin({
                  deadcode: {
                      keepFnArgs: true,
                  },
              }, {}),
          ],
      }

      // ...
  }
  ```
- or **alternatively** pretend in your code that this argument is used:

  ```js
  const errMiddleware = (err, req, res, _next) => {
      // ... your code ...
      // ...
      // cheat here:
      _next
  }
  ```